# Is it possible to connect WordPress Website (hosted on GoDaddy) to Google Cloud Platform Instance using Public IP?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, hosting, instance

I've been trying to connect my WordPress Website hosted on GoDaddy to Google Cloud Instance. I have checked the wp-config file, IP addresses, databases, authorized network and users. Everything is exactly how it should be. I just want to know if this connection is possible or I am shooting arrows in the dark.
Thanks

Comment: You can connect anything to a GCE instance, including a WP web-site. What exactly does you WP site need to access on the instance? Can share a minimal example of what you have tried and what did not work as you expected?

Comment: Thank you for your response Neo, but I was able to figure out the problem. I was using shared hosting plan which cannot be connected to GCP Instance. I was trying to connect the databse.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I was using Managed WordPress Hosting on GoDaddy which is shared hosting and shared hosting websites cannot be connected to GCP instances.
I had two options

1. Upgrade my hosting package to Dedicated Server.
2. Migrate my website to GCP and then connect.

I availed second option and it works now.